# Picking nib file in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm currently having the constructor of my UIViewController defined like this:

```
public MyViewController(int mode) : base ("MyViewController", null)
{
   //Initialize viewcontroller
}
```

I want to use different nib files under different circumstances based on the `mode` parameter. The problem is I can't run any code in the constructor before calling the base constructor.

I know it's possible to use the `[condition] ? [true_path] : [false_path]` syntax to pick between two nib strings, but I have to pick between four of them.

Is there any way to do this without resorting to adding new parameters to the `MyViewController` constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a static method to solve this problem.

Define it like this:

```
private static string GetNibFile(int mode)
{
    //Pick your nib file here, using a switch or something
    return "ChosenNibName";
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public MyViewController(int mode) : base (GetNibFile(mode), null)
{
   //Initialize viewcontroller
}
```

Comment: It works! (Altough I needed to add a ; after the return statement)
Thanks!